# Вопрос про IDE phpStorm upd + видео

Tags: jetbrains, phpstorm, ide

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdxxrsiuVnU

У меня есть два дива

[image: картинка]

При двойном клике на второй селектор, он выделится, как сделать чтоб он выделялся когда я сделаю двойной клик на первый, ide `phpStorm`

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос нормально для начала.

Comment: а что непонятного?

Comment: То что вам все понятно - это уже плюс. Случается, что народ даже не знает чего хочет в итоге.))

Малейшего понятия не имею о phpStorm, его инструментах, утилитах или библиотеках, которые там используются. Но так или иначе, данную задачу можно решить или же на чистом JS, или на JS-библиотеках (jQuery, MooTools, etc.). Поэтому [могу предложить такой вариант][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/n8ZBB/

Comment: Знаки `=` пропущены. Это такая задумка?

Comment: @Deonis, судя по всему, вопрос именно об IDE, а не о коде, @do4a, поправьте, если я не прав...

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, а вы предполагаете, что в IDE это реализуется на каком-то сверхновом и никому не известном языке программирования?

Comment: так щас я видео запишу

Comment: http://cs518502.vk.com/u8930220/videos/df1672c153.720.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто продвинуть мышь в сторону после двойного клика: [видео](http://vk.com/doc8930220_175677102)